# What is the power consumption of a MacBook Pro when sleeping

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power, power-nap

I wanted to know what's the power consumption of a MacBook Pro M2 Max or similar when sleeping, with Power Nap and network wakeup disabled.

I've searched and different sources say between 1W to 3W. Anybody has scientific data?

Comment: Apple does have power usage profiles on their web site for some machines (such as [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102839)) but no mention of sleep mode power consumption. Most people seem to go by how much battery usage there has been after X hours. 1-3W does sound about right though, which in real terms is neglible from a $$$ perspective if that's what you're interested in knowing. I'm sure there must be someone on this forum that has that type of machine *and* a plug-in watt meter that could run some tests for you. Saying that, some cheap meters don't measure usage that low.

Comment: It would be interesting to know to what extent PowerNap and Wake on Lan have any noticeable effect over an 8hr period.

Comment: Doing the math, 100 watt hours (the 16” battery) would be drained in 4 days at 1 W sleep or 6 weeks at 0.1 W sleep. My guess is with Power Nap and WOL off it’s less than the smaller of the two drain rates, but likely somewhere in the 0.0x range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s going to be a fraction of a watt since I can sleep my Mac for long weekends and there's zero usage reported in System Settings.

[image: System Settings - Battery on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1]

Perhaps someone with a third party app to read the mAh on their battery can do a test with it sleeping undisturbed for a week (or more) and get you a breakdown on power by dividing the drain on the battery by the time asleep.

[image: System Report / System Information on M2 MacBook]